# how to access ajax post variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If I use ajax to post like so:

```
$('a.publish').live('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('item_', '');
    var table= $(this).attr('rel');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "",
        data: 'publish=' + id + '&table=' + table,
        success: function () {
            $('#published_' + id).html(data);
            count();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**how do I access the post variable `table`?**

I am able to extract the `id` via:

```
if (isset($_POST['publish'])) {
    $id = intval($_POST['publish']);
    Nemesis::update("projects", "published = '1'", "id = '{$id}'");
    print "Active";
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['table']` or am I missing something? (And `.live` is deprecated in newer versions of jQuery)

Comment: You're doing it right by the looks of it. Did you check if your `a` had a `rel` attr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_POST['table']
```

will return the table variable.

If that's not working, check that the value is correct before submitting. Try to `console.log(table)` and/or check the network tab in firebug/chrome dev tools to see which agruments you sent.

[Have a look at the HTTP headers](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#http_headers) to see the values you're submitting to the server. If table is empty, the error is in jquery.

---

Server-side debugging might be doing something like `var_dump($_POST['table'])`
Try that also.

---

> but now the issue i have is getting the echo to work with
>   $('#published_' + id).html(data);

pass the data in the function. Like this:

`success: function (data) {
            $('#published_' + id).html(data);
            count();
        }`

Comment: yea its my first time using ajax and i read the way i wrote it wrong haha. i didnt know i was attributing the $id to the $_POST['publish'], and that was the issue. thanks ;)

Comment: but now the issue i have is getting the `echo` to work with `$('#published_' + id).html(data);`

Answer (score 0):

access variable like "publish",you can code

```
$table = $_POST['table'] die echo "var table is not available"
```

you can access the environment variable by $_GET[''] $_POST[''] and $_SERVER['']